# SwiftUI extract Childview with Bindings, @State

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following component in a view

```swift
HStack {
  TextField("New Note", text: $newNoteContent)
  .onSubmit(submitNewNote)
  .focused($newNoteIsFocused)
  if (!newNoteContent.isEmpty) {
    Button(action: submitNewNote) {
      Image(systemName: "checkmark")
    }
  }
}
```

The variables are defined as follows

```swift
@State private var newNoteContent: String = ""
@FocusState private var newNoteIsFocused: Bool

func submitNewNote() {
  Note.add(content: newNoteContent)
  newNoteContent = ""
  newNoteIsFocused = false
}
```

I would like to extract it and make it either a computed variable returning a view or a  function that returns a view (I dont know which is better). I want to extract it because I reuse a similar struct.

Full code in case its needed: https://github.com/charelF/RemindMeApp/blob/main/RemindMe/NotesView.swift

I have tried the following:

```swift
func editCell(
  noteContent: Binding<String>,
  submitFunc: @escaping () -> (),
  focus: FocusState<Bool>.Binding
) -> some View {
  return HStack {
    TextField("New Note", text: noteContent)
    .onSubmit(submitFunc)
    .focused(focus)
    if (!noteContent.isEmpty) {
      Button(action: submitFunc) {
        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But there are some errors and its generally just playing around -- I have no idea what I am really doing here and need some feedback/help.

---

#### Update from comment:

So I extracted the view as follows for now

```swift
struct ExtractedView: View {
  @State private var editNoteContent: String = ""
  @FocusState private var editNoteIsFocused: Bool
  @State private var editNote: Note? = nil
  
  func editExistingNote(note: Note?) {
    guard let note else { return }
    note.content = editNoteContent
    PersistenceController.shared.save()
    editNoteContent = ""
    editNoteIsFocused = false
    editNote = nil
  }
```

But I dont understand how to call it. If I call it with `ExtractedView()` then the code compiles and the app runs, but it crashes when I enter this path of the app. And when I call it like this:

```swift
ExtractedView(
  editNoteContent: editNoteContent,
  editNoteIsFocused: editNoteIsFocused,
  editNote: editNote
)
```

Then i get lots of errors ... [image]

Comment: Why wouldn't you just make it a `View`?  Why use a computed variable or return it from a function?  If you use a `View` then you can just pass the bindings.

Comment: Hmm I will try that one altough I had in mind I had a problem with it. I will update

Comment: So I tried but its not working but I dont understand how to do it correctly.

Comment: Your new extracted view looks incomplete, where is the `body` part and why are you adding new logic to it? Try to solve one issue at a time instead.

Comment: You would have `@Binding` in a subview, which you pass the `@State` properties to

Comment: It would also help if you could create a [mcve]

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes you are right I was a bit tired when I edited the question. It is fixed in the answer I just left.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for this comment, the `@Binding` solved the issue for me, I did not know that `@State` in parent maps to `@Binding` in the child. Regarding the mininmal reproducible example, I always aim to do so but sometime this takes a lot of effort especially in this case.. Hence I provided a link to a repo that can be cloned and ran in a few minutes.

Comment: There are lots of really good introduction to SwiftUI tutorials out there, including some from Apple.  It might be a good idea to work through some of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments and this answer here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682448 I got it to work. I extracted the view as follows:

```swift
struct EditNoteView: View {
  
  @Binding var noteContent: String
  @FocusState var isNoteFocused: Bool
  var onsubmit: () -> ()
  var placeholder: String
  
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      TextField(placeholder, text: $noteContent)
        .onSubmit(onsubmit)
        .focused($isNoteFocused)
      if (!noteContent.isEmpty) {
        Button(action: onsubmit) {
          Image(systemName: "checkmark")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then I call this child view from my parent view (inside the body) with

```swift
EditNoteView(
  noteContent: $newNoteContent,
  isNoteFocused: _newNoteIsFocused,
  onsubmit: submitNewNote,
  placeholder: "New Note"
)
```

Also in my parent views, I have the following definitions for the variables

```swift
@State private var newNoteContent: String = ""
@FocusState private var newNoteIsFocused: Bool
func submitNewNote() {
    Note.add(content: newNoteContent)
    newNoteContent = ""
    newNoteIsFocused = false
  }
```

The main takeaways is that all of the `@State` things map to `@Binding` in the childview, and the `@FocusState` maps to another `@FocusState`, but there is a `_` required before the parameter in the call.